# Is it safe to call size() method on moved-from vector?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, move-semantics

Standard specifies that STL containers, after begin *moved* (in this case we talk about `std::move` that enables move construction / assignment), are in *valid, but **unspecified** state*.

I belive that means we can only apply operations that require no preconditions. I recall that someone here, on Stackoverflow, claimed that to be true and after some checking I agreed. Unfortunately, I cannot recall what sources have I checked. Furthermore, I was not able to find relevant information in the standard.

From [`[container.requirements.general/4]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#4), table `62` (`[tab:container.req]`), we can see that `a.size()` has no preconditions. Does that mean this code is safe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v2 = std::move(v1);

    std::cout << v1.size(); // displaying size of the moved-from vector
}
```

It's *unspecified* what will this code print, but is it *safe*? Meaning, do we have *undefined behaviour* here?

EDIT: I don't believe this question will be too broad if I ask abour other containers. Will the answer be consistent among **all** other STL containers, including `std::string`?

Comment: To see what preconditions a standard container function/operation has see: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements

Comment: As an aside, there is no practical way for `.size()` to return anything except `0` here: the requirements on `vector( vector&& )` are such that *in the general case*, the buffer *must* be moved to the target vector, and the source vector cannot hold onto anything and must be empty.  However, an insane std library might be able to justify doing something different, especially for a vector of PODs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont so it's illegal for `vector(vector&& arg)` to simply call the relevant `swap(*this, arg)`? Where does it say that the moved-from vector must be empty?

Comment: @Fureeish This isn't `operator=`, it is move-construction.  There is nothing in the "destination" vector to swap out of.  Extra allocations can (in general) be observed; so cannot occur.  There are insane ways to get around this, but not in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no *undefined behavior* here, because of the lack of pre-conditions. The Standard guarantees that a moved-from container will be left in a valid but unspecified state. A valid state implies that anything that doesn't have preconditions can be invoked, but the result will be unpredictable.

So yeah, this is not UB, but definitely useless and a bad idea.